Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Please spend at least half a minute searching for the questions and related terms. When searching, use incognito on Chrome, and the private browsing equivalent on other browsers. If you have some time, then try using a proxy server, as that will give the most accurate results. See this related discussion.

Graduation review: not ready for graduation yet, but quality and engagement are good. The big area that needs work right now is growth (of course - more people need to find out about this place!). On the right track for now, hope it continues.

Final Results

How to display memory zones content on IDA Pro?
Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

What is "overlapping instructions" obfuscation?
Net Score: 10 (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

How to detect a virtualized environment?
Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

How do I see the parameters passed to RegOpenKeyEx, and set a conditional breakpoint?
Net Score: 10 (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

Creating IDA Pro debugger plugins - API documentation and examples?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

What are the different types of packers?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

Why does an executable give an error when opened in $tool?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

How to handle stripped binaries with GDB? No source, no symbols and GDB only shows addresses?
Net Score: 9 (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

How can I check I've moved outside the stack without triggering a protection fault?
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

What is fault-injection reverse engineering? What are the techniques involved?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)



I looked at some other site eval results and it seems we have higher quality content than other sites. Kudos to [reverseengineering.se] !

Its been 70+ days and all in all, we seem to be doing decently. Our community seems to have started to take shape. 
Some positives first :

Our community has been growing at a good rate in terms of new users.
RE is turning up frequently in search results
Questions have been getting answers within the hour, generally. This is one of the things SE is known for, and RE is doing well in this front.

Some not so positives :

I was going through the reviews of some users and some reviews seem to be inaccurate. There were a few posts in the First Post review queue that got reviewed with Looks Good even though they had grammatical errors and missing formatting. 

For users having more than 1k rep, you should directly edit questions to correct such problems as and when you come across it. 
For users not having the editing privilege yet, you should also suggest edits  to posts, but only if you see multiple issues with the post (such as grammatical errors + formatting errors).

Just one person has earned the Announcer badge. This is not a problem, per se, but an indicator that we aren't sharing questions enough. We have many high quality questions and answers, that are just crying out for attention! 

Also, there is one major trend that the site has been seeing and I think best to describe this as a question ;-) 
Are we RCE.SE or RE.SE?
We have had a very small portion of hardware related questions. If we really want to be RE.SE, then I think we need to promote the site to hardware engineers as well. This can be done by asking and answering more hardware questions and getting the community ad up on the hardware-related SE sites, mainly EE (posted here).
Some other scope related discussions :
Does the site scope include biology?
Is discussing social phenomena on-topic?

Wait wait wait. The scope of the review as outlined at the top was about the search visibility, not about reviewing for grammatical and spelling errors. In fact I had been called out (by you, IIRC) when I was going through posts systematically correcting errors, both in the text and the tags.

@0xC0000022L It was great that you were working on that. I had only pointed out that dont do too many at the same time. Just do the ones you may come across and a max of 3-4 at a time. Also, this is not targeted at any one person, but a general trend I saw. The post above in the last line says Site's health.

@AsheeshR and the reasoning behind that was that it throws the order of questions out of wack by basically bumping them back to the top of the queue right? And it wouldn't be good to have all the newest questions on the 2nd or 3rd page.

@cb88 Exactly..
